# Ruby On Rails testing User Model with RSpec - password and password_confirmation doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, tdd

it's my first post. I start to learn Ruby and Ruby On Rails framework.

I want to test User Model with RSpec and i have problem with pass validation of **password** and **password_confirmation**.

Code: https://github.com/paw3lgora/gCMS/blob/master/spec/models/user_spec.rb

I have problem with line: **it { should validate_confirmation_of(:password) }**

I don't wanna use devise gem or has_secure_password method from BCrypt because i learn Ruby and I want to implement my authentcation systems from scratch and add Argon2 in the future.

This give me error like:

> 1) User validation password should validate that
>   :password_confirmation matches :password
>        Failure/Error: it { should validate_confirmation_of(:password) }
>
> ```
>    User did not properly validate that :password_confirmation matches
>    :password.
>      After setting :password_confirmation to ‹"some value"›, then setting
>      :password to ‹"different value"›, the matcher expected the User to be
>      invalid and to produce the validation error "doesn't match Password"
>      on :password_confirmation. The record was indeed invalid, but it
>      produced these validation errors instead:
>
>      * name: ["Nazwa użytkownika nie może być pusta.", "Nazwa użytkownika
>        jest za krótka. Minimum 2 znaki."]
>      * email: ["Nie podałeś emaila.", "Email jest za krótki. Minimum 5
>        znaków.", "Podałeś złą nazwę użytkownika."]
>      * password_confirmation: ["Hasła nie pasują do siebie."]
>  # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```

Help me guys! :)

Comment: If you are using shoulda matchers you need to use  `validate_confirmation_of(:password).with_message("Hasła nie pasują do siebie.")`. It only works with english by default since the expectations are based on the text of the error message.

Comment: Thank you very much man!

Answer (score 0):

If you read the whole message carefully you'll see

> The record was indeed invalid, but it
>        produced these validation errors instead:

Which means that the validation failed, but the matcher expects the validation errors to be exactly as specified. And there were more.

You have two options:

- add all failed validation expectations in your spec
- prepare the user object in such way that `:name` and `:email` are valid.